# Is it possible to manually set the scale and ticks on a plot.ly 3D scatter graph?

Tags: javascript, plotly

I have a basic plot.ly 3D scatter graph with various paths specified in three dimensions.  After three days of reading documentation, I still haven't found a way to define the tick interval of my axes. It seems to be auto-generating them based on my data, which I don't want.  In effect, I need my three axes to be in a 1:1:1 ratio, is this possible?

```
<style>html, body { height: 100%; }</style>
<div id="myDiv" style="width: 100%; height: 100%"></div>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified plotly.js JavaScript -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>

<script>
var data = [
  {
    x: [-886, -719],
    y: [-4785, -5192],
    z: [527, 501],
    type: 'scatter3d'
  },
  {
    x: [-1782, -92],
    y: [1740, -5172],
    z: [18, 252],
    type: 'scatter3d'
  },
  {
    x: [3844, -450],
    y: [35, -5185],
    z: [20, 219],
    type: 'scatter3d'
  },
  {
    x: [2770, 761],
    y: [2360, -5122],
    z: [246, 96],
    type: 'scatter3d'
  },
  {
    x: [3800, 546],
    y: [-3419, -5215],
    z: [57, 311],
    type: 'scatter3d'
  },
  {
    x: [-340, 775],
    y: [-3893, -5189],
    z: [573, 135],
    type: 'scatter3d'
  },
  {
    x: [-3141, -41],
    y: [3677, -5205],
    z: [18, 383],
    type: 'scatter3d'
  },
  {
    x: [19, -546],
    y: [261, -5181],
    z: [74, 93],
    type: 'scatter3d'
  },
  {
    x: [3, 789],
    y: [394, -5165],
    z: [112, 421],
    type: 'scatter3d'
  }
];
var layout = {
  // height: 700,
  // width: 700,
  xaxis: {
    range: [-5000, 5000]
  },
  yaxis: {
    range: [-5000, 5000]
  }
};
Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);
</script>
```

Code demonstration: https://rocket-league-replays.github.io/3d-hitmaps/

Answer (score 2):

I am less familiar with the javascript plotly api, this answer was written with python in mind.  Hopefully it also helps in your situation.

If I understand your question properly you want to set the tickmode for the axis, and depending on the mode you pick you also want to set either nticks; tick0 and dticks; or tickvals.

the following is taken from: https://plot.ly/python/reference/#layout-scene-xaxis-tickmode  a difficult to effectively search, but very useful page.  The javascript version of the page is: https://plot.ly/javascript/reference/#layout-scene-xaxis-tickmode

> **tickmode (enumerated: "auto" | "linear" | "array" )** 
>   Sets the tick mode for this axis. If "auto", the number of ticks is set via `nticks`. If "linear", the placement of the ticks is determined by a starting position `tick0` and a tick step `dtick` ("linear" is the default value if `tick0` and `dtick` are provided). If "array", the placement of the ticks is set via `tickvals` and the tick text is `ticktext`. ("array" is the default value if `tickvals` is provided).

Answer (score 0):

Again this is for python, but in the scene option there is a way to set the range of the x, y, or z axis using the range(list) option in the xaxis (or yaxis or zaxis) below is an example code.

```
 scene = dict(xaxis=dict(gridcolor='rgb(0, 0, 0)',
                                    zerolinecolor='rgb(0, 0, 0)',
                                    showbackground=False,
                                    range = (minX,maxX)),
                        yaxis=dict(gridcolor='rgb(0, 0, 0)',
                                   zerolinecolor='rgb(0, 0, 0)',
                                   showbackground=False,
                                   range = (minY, maxY)),
                        zaxis=dict(gridcolor='rgb(0, 0, 0)',
                                    zerolinecolor='rgb(0, 0, 0)',
                                    showbackground=False,
                                   range = (minZ, maxZ)))
 fig['layout'].update(scene)
```

here is the documentation: https://plot.ly/python/reference/#layout-xaxis-range  and for java https://plot.ly/javascript/reference/#layout-xaxis-range

Answer (score 0):

Yes, sure. That information is possible to be seen in [Plotly's documentation](https://plotly.com/javascript/3d-axes/#range-of-axes) on how to format axes for 3d charts.

Code wise, what you want is something like this

```
var layout = {
  scene:{
     aspectmode: "manual",
   aspectratio: {
     x: 1, y: 1, z: 1,
    },
   xaxis: {
    nticks: 100,
    range: [-5000, 5000],
  },
   yaxis: {
    nticks: 100,
    range: [-5000, 5000],
  },
   zaxis: {
   nticks: 100,
   range: [-5000, 5000],
  }},
};
```